# Angular 7 application, I want to do an if() condition that checks the Input() value passed from parent

Tags: input, conditional-statements, angular7, disable

I am passing data from parent to child.  In the HTML, i can see the value of the Input() variable.  However, on my TS file, when I try to do a conditional to check the value of Input() it is always an empty string.  Here is my code for the child:

```
@Input() checkDbStatus = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
    this.dbStatusCheck();
}

// disables all controls in a form group
disableControl(group: FormGroup){
  Object.keys(group.controls).forEach((key: string) => {
    const abstractControl = group.get(key);
    abstractControl.disable();
  })
}

// disable form controls if dbStatus !== update
dbStatusCheck() {
    if(this.checkDbStatus !== 'update') {
      this.disableControl(this.demographicsSectionOne);
      this.disableControl(this.demographicsSectionTwo);
      this.disableControl(this.demographicsSectionThree);
      this.disableControl(this.demographicsSectionFour);
      this.disableControl(this.demographicsSectionFive);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the ngChange lifecycle.

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

```
export class YourComponent implements OnChanges

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

  if (changes.checkDbStatus.currentValue !== changes.checkDbStatus.previousValue) {
    this.doStatusCheck();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set and get input() function
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

_checkDbStatus: any;

@Input() set checkDbStatus(data: any) {

this._checkDbStatus = data;
this.dbStatusCheck(data)

}

get checkDbStatus(){return this._checkDbStatus }